celery + msgpack: contains extra data
I have a test celery application. It has a single task consisting of a chain of a starting task, a group, and a finishing task.
# each of these simply prints the argument it received
store_t = chain(crunch_file.s(), group(process_1.s(), process_2.s()), finisher.s())
store_t.apply_async(("file1",))

I use msgpack to serialize/deserialize.
Msgpack works with most cases, notably, it works without the group, but for this perhaps somewhat complex construct of a chain including a group, it gives me the following error:

Can't decode message body: DecodeError(ExtraData([['file1'], {},
{'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'chain': [{'task':
'celery.chord', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {'kwargs': {'tasks': [{'task':
'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.process_1', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {},
'options': {'task_id': '93c625f2-0a14-4656-be1e-4d1d637c61e2',
'reply_to': '2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737', 'chord': {'task':
'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.finisher', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {},
'options': {'task_id': 'c3094358-3a0e-4ad6-b453-d8dd5fe84450',
'reply_to': '2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737'}, 'subtask_type':
None, 'immutable': False}, 'group_index': 0}, 'subtask_type': None,
'immutable': False}, {'task': 'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.process_2',
'args': [], 'kwargs': {}, 'options': {'task_id':
'8396895c-342d-4c3d-99dc-3e65d4a97c35', 'reply_to':
'2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737', 'chord': {'task':
'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.finisher', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {},
'options': {'task_id': 'c3094358-3a0e-4ad6-b453-d8dd5fe84450',
'reply_to': '2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737'}, 'subtask_type':
None, 'immutable': False}, 'group_index': 1}, 'subtask_type': None,
'immutable': False}]}, 'header': {'task': 'celery.group', 'args':
[]}}, 'options': {'task_id': '43b33291-05a8-4696-bf69-ead99a9a8628',
'chord': {'task': 'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.finisher', 'args': [],
'kwargs': {}, 'options': {'task_id':
'c3094358-3a0e-4ad6-b453-d8dd5fe84450', 'reply_to':
'2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737'}, 'subtask_type': None,
'immutable': False}, 'root_id': None, 'parent_id': None},
'subtask_type': 'group', 'immutable': False}], 'body': {'task':
'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.finisher', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {},
'options': {'task_id': 'c3094358-3a0e-4ad6-b453-d8dd5fe84450',
'reply_to': '2654c01b-7b94-32ae-8088-00a3e9815737'}, 'subtask_type':
None, 'immutable': False}}],
b'\xa7options\x81\xa7task_id\xd9$43b33291-05a8-4696-bf69-ead99a9a8628\xacsubtask_type\xa5chord\xa9immutable\xc2\xa5chord\xc0'))
[type:'application/msgpack' encoding:'utf-8' headers:{'lang': 'py',
'task': 'pyces.test_tasks.test_tasks.crunch_file', 'id':
'3ffd4f22-d021-413f-afc2-06dd10569176', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None,
'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0,
'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id':
'3ffd4f22-d021-413f-afc2-06dd10569176', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr':
"('file1',)", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen178287@bunghole',
'ignore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'stamped_headers':
None, 'stamps': {}}]

I have tried the umsgpack module instead of msgpack, and when I use that it tells me it has a duplicate key kwargs. But I cannot actually locate it.
